# MySql partitioned table - select between date range using PK very slow compared to date IN (...) clause

Tags: mysql, date, amazon-rds, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a very large table consisting of approximately 3 Million records per day.

The following query is so slow

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM summary_by_to_days_range 
WHERE(record_date BETWEEN '2019-03-12' AND '2019-03-15')
AND unit_id = 1148210
AND enum_key IN (9, 10, 38, 311)
GROUP BY unit_id, record_date
ORDER BY record_date DESC;
```

With the following results:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  rows   | filtered |    Extra    | possible_keys |   key   |                     partitions                      |
+---------+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 9072566 |        4 | Using where | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | from20190312,from20190313,from20190314,from20190315 |
+---------+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Compared to

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM summary_by_to_days_range 
WHERE(record_date IN ('2019-03-12','2019-03-13','2019-03-14','2019-03-15'))
AND unit_id = 1148210
AND enum_key IN (9, 10, 38, 311)
GROUP BY unit_id, record_date
ORDER BY record_date DESC;
```

With much better results:

```
+------+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| rows | filtered |    Extra    | possible_keys |   key   |                     partitions                      |
+------+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|   16 |      100 | Using where | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | from20190312,from20190313,from20190314,from20190315 |
+------+----------+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

And I can't understand why.. I'm supplying PK values, the only difference is the Between date clause!

The Table schema

```sql
  `CREATE TABLE summary_by_to_days_range (
  `record_date` date NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `enum_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `str_value` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`record_date`,`unit_id`,`enum_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(record_date))
(PARTITION START_h VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from20181231 VALUES LESS THAN (737425) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from20190101 VALUES LESS THAN (737426) ENGINE = InnoDB,
.
.
PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB)`
```

I also tried partitioning by key, by range column by hash of DAYOFYEAR() all resulting with the same disappointing result..

Anyone?

Comment: You've said that BETWEEN is slower but provided no evidence to support this - you've shown us the estimates from the stats - but that is just a guess. How did you test the performance of the queries? What metrics did you get?

Comment: Just ran the queries again (without the explain).First query is still running while I'm typing this response.  Second query Total Time : 0.149 sec. Don't understand what kind of evidence you want.. I was pretty explicit. No need to down-vote if you can't help

Comment: Update - first query Total Time     : 6 min 24 sec

Comment: EXPLAIN does not necessarily reflect the actual cost of a query - understanding why they are different is key to solving a lot of performance problems

Comment: I don't mind creating a code that types all possible dates in a certain range but for me what's peculiar, is that the BETWEEN clause doesn't execute as expected. I asked the question because after visiting a ton of sites I still don't have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Usually* it is inefficient to start the `PRIMARY KEY` with the column(s) of the "partition key".  After all, first comes the "partition pruning"; why then filter on the same stuff?

*Usually* it is inefficient to start any composite index with a column that will be used in a "range" test.  It is subtle, but I think this explains the difference you are seeing.  With `IN` (your second query), more fields in the PK can be used, thereby running faster.

And, no, the Optimizer is smart enough to understand how "dates" work.  Otherwise, it could do your second query as fast as the first.  (This crudely addresses some of the Comments.)

(for reference)

```
WHERE record_date BETWEEN '2019-03-12' AND '2019-03-15'
  AND unit_id = 1148210
  AND enum_key IN (9, 10, 38, 311)

`record_date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`record_date`,`unit_id`,`enum_key`)

PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(record_date))
```

Let's address both of my comments as follows.

Change to

```
PRIMARY KEY(unit_id, enum_key, record_date)
```

With this PK, *either* of your `SELECTs` will

1. Prune down to the 4 partitions (as before)
2. Quickly filter down to the desired `unit_id`.  (I suspect this is where most of the efficiency is.)
3. Jump through the rows for `enum_key`
4. Check that `record_date` is correct.

I'm glad to set the `start` and `future` partitions.  (Perhaps you have already read [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).)

A note:  It can be somewhat inefficient to have more than about 50 partitions.  If you have (or will have) more than that, consider using weekly or monthly partitions.  This will have a slight impact on *my* PK, but not until step 4.

As for `PARTITION BY HASH`... I have found *no* performance gain using it.  (Or at least none that could not be achieved some other way.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I did read the great article you wrote prior to creating the table :) Changing the order of the primary key made the difference!.

Comment: I also ended up testing many partition types. finally when i partitioned by KEY(record_date), gave slightly better results when running an EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON.. but of course this way the table will get larger every year.. Our table gets additional 3 Million records a day so we have no choice but to partition BY RANGE(..) like you specified in the through article you wrote